# Angular: Custom form components do not react to value change - like 2 way data binding

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

So I am creating my own form component that has a similar issue to the one here in this article

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-custom-form-controls-with-reactive-forms-and-ngmodel

I forked the code there to illustrate the point ...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8afwjx?file=src/app/app.component.html

You can see that where ngModel is used, the other element that uses the same one gets updated all the time....becuase of 2 way data binding

but down in the reactive form, when I am trying to use the formControlName, when I toggle the control (either of them) the form gets udpated, but the other control not.

How do I make my custom control to react to value changes correctly? do I need to subscribe to it? I find it odd

Answer (score 0):

You can bind singe formControl instance to multiple input using formControl directive.To keep the controls in sync we can set the value property of the form control.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label for="switch-2">Reactive Forms</label>
  <app-switch id="switch-2" [value]="switchControl.value" [formControl]="switchControl"></app-switch>

  <label for="switch-2">Reactive Forms2</label>
  <app-switch id="switch-2" [value]="switchControl.value" [formControl]="switchControl"></app-switch>

  <hr />
  <button>Submit</button>

  <br />
  <h2>Form value</h2>
  {{ myForm.value | json }}
</form>
```

[**Live Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grlq22?file=src/app/app.component.html)

You can check more information here in Corylan [Article](https://coryrylan.com/blog/syncing-multiple-reactive-form-inputs-in-angular)

Comment: Hello Chellappan, thank you for taking time and post an answer. I immensely appreciate! While your solution works, it is quite more convoluted to set it up for every form field... (setting a new getter for form Control foe every new one) and then use the value on it....  I would like formControlName much better, because is neater and cleaner... and the whole point in my case, of using custom components is to reduce markup and boiler palte code when setting the forms up... if possible would like to absorb this in the custom control component itself

Comment: YEs i  see your point. In that case you can create reusable forms something like to encapsulate the logic:https://coryrylan.com/blog/building-reusable-forms-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like use `[value]` and `formControl` in the same tag. So, another approach is use ngModel for one of the "inputs"

```
  <app-switch id="switch-2" 
         [ngModel]="myForm.value.mySwitch" 
         (ngModelChange)="myForm.get('mySwitch').setValue($event)"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
  </app-switch>
```

NOTE: the situation the same FormControl in two inputs differents happens always -it's not only in your custom form Control-